# Value of these multivariable limits given some assumption

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $a\in \mathbb{R^n}$.

What is the value of limit $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|(f(x)-f(a))(g(x)-g(a))|}{||x-a||}$$

$||n||$ just means the modulus of vector.

I tried using the definition, but I cannot go about it. I have a hint that its value has to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {|f(x)-f(a)} {\|x-a\|}$ is bounded and so is $\frac {|g(x)-g(a)} {\|x-a\|}$. Multiply these two (and multiply numerator and denominator by $\|x-a\|$)  to see that the limit is necessarily $0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? And what do you mean by bounded?

Comment: I am sure you can see the argument if you write out the expression in the case $n=1$. If $\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a}$ tends to a finite limit it is bounded in some neighborhood of $a$, right?.

Comment: Yeah? But how in the case of $n\neq1$?

Comment: Use definition of derivative. If $L=f'(a)$ split $f(x)-f(a)$ as $f(x)-f(a)-L(x-a)+L(x-a)$  and note that $\frac {L(x)-L(a)} {\|x-a\|}$ is bounded.

Comment: I cannot get your logic. First, $L=f'(a)$ is the total derivative right? Then what does $L(x)$ mean?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal By definition $L$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$. Since $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$, $L(x)$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: Cool, so on proving bounded, we use sandwich theorem, right?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Yes, you are right.